# Principal is calling you (teacher) in his chamber or principal want to see you in the chamber

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

1. The principal is calling you (the teacher) to her office.
2. The principal wants to see you in her office.

Can we use both sentences to mean that the principal wants to meet a teacher in her chamber who was told by a student to fetch the teacher?

Answer (score 2):

Socially, the idea would usually be expressed more softly:

> The principal **would like** to see you in her office

"wants to see you" is more forceful, and, depending on who's saying it, might mean that the person whom the principal wants to see is in trouble.

The verb "call" is usually only used descriptively:

> The principal **called him** into her office

or

> What did the principal want, when she **called you** into her office?

Answer (score 1):

> The principal wants to see you in his/her office

is the usual phrase used to express one is being summoned to see the principal.

Remember:

> princi**pal** is the person, because they are your "pal", principle is the idea.

Answer (score -5):

*Principal wants to see you in his chamber* sounds more suitable for this sentence.

**When someone wants to see you particully** = *means someone wants to talk to you, or to have a conversation, it may be a serious conversation, business or even just a friendly conversation*.

Comment: I don’t know of anyone who would use _chamber_ instead of _office_ – unless we were talking about a judge.

Comment: I just tried to rewrite the question OP's question. I wouldn't use it either, I guess no one uses it nowadays.